# generate url in smart contract, based on block.chainid and address(this)

Tags: assembly, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

For the past few days I have been looking into creating a simple function to generate a url based on block.chainid (uint256) and address(this).

The idea is as follows:

```
function url() public view returns (string memory) {
        return string.concat("https://website.com/token/", Strings.toString(block.chainid), "/", Strings.toHexString(address(this)));
    }
```

The above works with the `import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Strings.sol";` library, but deployment costs increase by 300K gas.

I have been looking into doing this in assembly by converting everythings to bytes, concating them and converting it into a string. Which in most tries only increase gas by a few thousand, but all attempts failed as I'm very new to assembly.

Anyone knows the propper assambly for this :)?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Because the url() function is view based on, I assume the gas cost does not serve any practical limitation, as it should not be called within a transaction?

Comment: It makes the initial deployment more expansive, and that is what I want to lower.